# Proving that a function is non-measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to show that the following real valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ is nonmeasurable:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x &\text{$x \in E$} \\ -x &\text{$x \in [0,1] \setminus E$} \end{cases} $$

where $E$ is a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$. How could one do this?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

If the function was measurable then $f^{-1}([0,1])$ would be a measurable set.

Comment: Is $f^{-1}([0,1])$ nonmeasurable because it is equal to $E$? Sorry, I am a little lost.

Comment: @brdcastguy: Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Suppose $0 \in E$, then what is the set $\{x | f(x) \geq 0 \}$?

(If $0 \notin E$, then use $f(x) \leq 0$ instead.)

Comment: Would $f^{-1}([0,\infty)) = E$, which is nonmeasurable, so $f$ is nonmeasurable? Is that the conclusion I need to make?

Comment: It is indeed...

Answer (score 1):

The inverse image of a measurable set under a measurable function must be measurable. Were $f$ to be measurable, $g(x) =  f(x) - x$ is also measurable We know that $\{0\}$ is a measurable subset of the line. However, $g^{-1}(\{0\}) = E$ is not measurable. Hence $g$ is not measurable.  But if $g$ is not measurable, then $f$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

How about proving that if $f$ is any measurable function, then so is
$$
x\mapsto\frac{f(x)}{x}.\tag{1}
$$
For your function $f$, the inverse image of the set $\{1\}$ under the function $(1)$ is $E$, which would therefore be measurable.

Comment: works too. There's a panoply of ways to do this.